# Tag Assessments should be Tag Assessment

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderation

I recommend changing the name of the "assessments" tag to "assessment".

I think "assessment" (describes an action) has a very different interpretation than "assessments" (a plural noun describing a thing). "What form of assessment do you use in your class?", vs "What assessments do you use?"
I think the latter will be almost universally interpreted as tests/exams. The verb form is much broader and will normally be interpreted as a process. I prefer the verb form (assessment).

Note that there is already a tag for tests and another for exam. Those two should be folded into one tag.

Can it be easily changed? A mod edit: assessments as a tag to assessment? Note that an ordinary user cannot create assessment as it is too close to the existing tag. Mod intervention is needed.

Assessment (the process) can be formative or summative, formal or informal. An assessment answers the question, "what do my students know?"

Tests/quizzes are a specific sort of assessment, involving questions that get answered, often in secured environments, and are traditionally weighted heavily in grading. Assessment generally can be, and sometimes should be, decoupled from grading. The issues is *not* singular forms v plural forms. That is only an issue if both forms indicate things (i.e. nouns, not processes-verbs).

The current wiki entry (by Buffy) is more aligned with the verb/action form rather than the noun/thing form. Assessment is a process of evaluating the student's work. It need not be via exam.

Note that "assessment" isn't actually a verb, but it is a noun describing an action "to assess". Whereas "assessments" is usually interpreted in education as one particular form of the result of an assessment, but is normally interpreted narrowly.

Comment: I 100% agree. Nice subtle observation.

Comment: I, too, agree. As stated in my other meta post, I would suggest folding both tests and exams into this category as well.

Comment: @Peter I'm not positive about merging 3 into one. In fact, I find it advantageous to get instructors to think of assessment completely separately from testing. There is too much emphasis on grading in technical fields. For me, that argues to keep them separate. Look at the wiki for assessments, now. I tried to capture that. But clearly, the other two are one concept as their wiki shows.

Comment: @Buffy But grading != assessment need not be conflated. Indeed formative assessment involves no “grading.” Yet formative and summative assessments should be connected, so whether graded or not, it’s all the same conversation at the HS level.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Most people assume exams are about grading, I think. I don't want them to think that assessment is about grading, which merging all three will encourage.